# Is it possible to register a new app with soundcloud API using a custom http protocol in electron?

Tags: soundcloud, electron

I'm currently building an electron soundcloud desktop app to learn Electron & ReactJS. I have seen an app use a custom http protocol ([link to electron docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md)) to recieve the callback for getting the authentication token. Today I wanted to register my app on developers.soundcloud.com. The application link sends you to a google form, but the redirect url you need to add here is required to have a http(s)://.

Is it actually possible to request something like this "soundtop://oauth/callback"?

Comment: Could be good to know if we basically can register a new app.